# Prevent Mail.app from Checking Mail At Start-Up

Tags: macos, mac, macbook, apple-mail

Is there a way to prevent the Mail.app from checking mail immediately after it starts-up, or at least have it prompt for a password first?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes just remove the password from the account(s) and it will prompt for a password on next launch.

Another way to do it is to uncheck the "Include when automatically checking new messages" checkbox under the advanced tab in the account preferences. This will make it so mail is only checked when you click get mail.

Comment: I tried unchecking the "Include when automatically checking new messages" option, but it still checks on start up. The password tip worked though. Thanks!

Comment: @RHPT - If the solution worked please consider accepting the answer. Thanks.